# How to throw an exception after a period of time if a certain line is not reached?

Tags: java, stalled

I have a problem when tryig to connect to a server using java.

Lets say that on line:

```
server.connect()
```

the program just stalls, no exceptions are thrown.

What I would like to do is throw an exception after 5 seconds if it is stalled. But since I can't get to the next line how would this be possible?

something like

```
if(after 5 sec server.connect is stalled){
throw an exception
 }
```

And would that even solve the problem?

Comment: What is this server? Show code of server declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this:

```
connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);//This value is in Mili seconds
```

Comment: In the API it says:  
 void  setTimeout(int timeout) sets the timeout setting.

Now, this works, it throws the exception.

What I'm wondering is if this is only thrown if I cannot connect. Or if it will be thrown after 5sec if it is open. Let's say I'm uploading lots of files and they take longer than the timeout?

Comment: @SeanMc: Few clarifications I need, you are uploading the files or saving them to a database?

Comment: @SeanMc: For your clarification, if you have a huge file and which cann't be uploaded in 5 seconds, then also an exception will be raised in 5 seconds.

Comment: I'm uploading SFTP to a server to be saved in a folder

Comment: @SeanMc: Then I don't have to change anything.. ;) Hope it solved your problem.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is another way to do this because I don't want to rely on the timeout incase it timesout on my files during the upload?